# Android Game Crash (NullPointerException) upon end game

Tags: android, debugging, nullpointerexception

I was designing a game that was working until I added the feature of saving score in the Main Activity. Once I did, the score saving worked, but at each endgame, the game crashes with the following error code:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.inputmethodservice.IInputMethodWrapper.setSessionEnabled(IInputMethodWrapper.java:280)
            at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethod$Stub.onTransact(IInputMethod.java:129)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:407)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-20 10:18:09.961     944-1573/? I/InputMethodManagerService﹕ IME STATUS OFF
06-20 10:18:09.961     944-1573/? W/InputMethodManagerService﹕ Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 15857 uid 10202
06-20 10:18:09.971  20141-20718/? W/chromium﹕ [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
06-20 10:18:09.981  20682-20682/? W/dalvikvm﹕ method Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ListViewCompat;.lookForSelectablePosition incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ListView;
06-20 10:18:09.981  20141-20210/? I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
06-20 10:18:09.981  20141-20724/? I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
06-20 10:18:09.991  20141-20724/? W/BaseRuntimeLoader﹕ don't searchcom.lge.telephony.msim.QcomMSimTelephonyManagerAdaptor class
06-20 10:18:09.991  20141-20724/? W/BaseRuntimeLoader﹕ don't searchcom.lge.telephony.msim.MtkMSimTelephonyManagerAdaptor class
06-20 10:18:09.991  20141-20724/? W/BaseRuntimeLoader﹕ don't searchcom.lge.telephony.msim.QcomMSimTelephonyManagerAdaptor class
06-20 10:18:09.991  20141-20724/? W/BaseRuntimeLoader﹕ don't searchcom.lge.telephony.msim.MtkMSimTelephonyManagerAdaptor class
06-20 10:18:10.021  20495-20495/? V/RenderScript﹕ Application requested CPU execution
```

This is how I structured my saving: at the end of the game (represented by boolean gameOver in game class), my handler would be notified and then extract the score from the game class and then save using a saveScore method which utilizes SharedPreferences.

I'm not sure why it would crash, but maintain the newest saved score.
The code mentioned above is shown below:

MainActivity:

```
Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {public void run() {if (Game.getGameOver())
            saveScore(Game.getScore());
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
    } };
 public void saveScore(int score)

{
    if (score>getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 0).getInt("key",0))
    {SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putInt("key", score);
    editor.commit();}
    scoreTextView.setText(getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 0).getInt("key",0));
}
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Game= (Game)findViewById(R.id.Game_canvas);
        timerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        scoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        scoreTextView.setText(getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", 0).getInt("key", 0)
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
    }
```

GameClass (extends View)

```
private boolean gameOver=false;

public boolean getGameOver()
{


    if (condition) {
        gameOver = true;
    }
    else
    gameOver=false;
    return gameOver;
}
public int getScore()
{

    return score;
}
```

Thanks so much!!!

Edit: I ran it again and this is the following message

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xbb8
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:245)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4042)
        at nocompany.game.MainActivity.saveScore(MainActivity.java:50)
        at nocompany.game.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:78)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)\
```

I suspect it may just be a problem of not defining a String in strings.xml for the SharedPreferences. I'll check. Nvm. It didn't work.

Edit: The error was trying to pass int into string.

Comment: passing an `int` to `setText` works only if the int comes from `R.string`. Wrap your int int `String.valueOf()`

Comment: Thanks! I just had to turn my text to string and it went ok.